# Python (3.7) asyncio, worker task with while loop and a custom signal handler

Tags: python-3.x, redis, signals, python-asyncio, worker

I'm trying to understand the pattern for indefinitely running asyncio Tasks
and the difference that a custom loop signal handler makes.
I create workers using `loop.create_task()` so that they run concurrently.

In my regular workers' code I am polling for data and act accordingly when data is there.

I'm trying to handle the shutdown process gracefully on a signal.
When a signal is delivered - I again `create_task()` with the shutdown function, so that currently running tasks continue, and shutdown gets executed in next iteration of the event loop.
Now - when a single worker's `while` loop doesn't actually do any IO or work then it prevents the signal handler from being executed. It never ends and does not give back execution so that other tasks could be run.

When I don't attach a custom signal handler to a loop and run this program, then a signal is delivered and the program stops. I assume it's a main thread that stops the loop itself.
This is obviously different from trying to schedule a (new) shutdown task on a running loop, because that running loop is stuck in a single coroutine which is blocked in a while loop and doesn't give back any control or time for other tasks.

Is there any standard pattern for such cases?
Do I need to `asyncio.sleep()` if there's no work to do, do I replace the while loop with something else (e.g. rescheduling the work function itself)?

If the `range(5)` is replaced with `range(1, 5)` then all workers do await asyncio.sleep,
but if one of them does not, then everything gets blocked. How to handle this case, is there any standard approach?

The code below illustrates the problem.

```
async def shutdown(loop, sig=None):
    print("SIGNAL", sig)
    tasks = [t for t in asyncio.all_tasks()
             if t is not asyncio.current_task()]

    [t.cancel() for t in tasks]

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    # handle_task_results(results)
    loop.stop()


async def worker(intval):
    print("start", intval)
    while True:
        if intval:
            print("#", intval)
            await asyncio.sleep(intval)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

for sig in {signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM}:
    loop.add_signal_handler(
        sig,
        lambda s=sig: asyncio.create_task(shutdown(loop, sig=s)))

workers = [loop.create_task(worker(i)) for i in range(5)]  # this range

loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: It turns out my problem lies in polling. I'm using aioredis BLPOP in my workers and in case the connection pool is too small everything simply hangs without any indication. No trace even with loop.set_debug, -X dev or PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG.

Comment: For anybody coming here: I dug into the code and found out the problem was indeed with the underlying connection being blocked until timeout occurs. As long as the connection is blocked, each worker needs to wait for it (aioredis returns a coroutine when a connection is not free), and everything slows down. Thus, the next iteration of the event loop may happen only after the scheduled awaitables finish, so it's a timeout multiplied by the number of workers. Only then the signal handler (the shutdown task) may be scheduled. I find this "schedule a shutdown task" quirky.